# How to reverse-engineer a webkit matrix3d transform

Tags: css, matrix, webkit, css-transforms

I've got a cube element being rotated and translated in a 3d space.

I want to find out *just* the rotateY portion of this transform at a given time.  Is this possible?

I have:

```
var cube = document.getElementById("cube");
var transform = getComputedStyle(cube).webkitTransform;

//the value of transform is:
// matrix3d(-1, 0, 0.00000000000000012246467991473532, 0, 
//           0, 1, 0, 0, 
//          -0.00000000000000012246467991473532, 0, -1, 0, 
//           0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Help? :-)

Comment: getting y value of the transformation? you may want to take a look at translate(). which converts matrix form to value. more on this here [translate transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform-function#translate())

Comment: Maybe I don't follow, but I'm stuck with this matrix3d, the transformation is being applied for me by someone else's code.  I'm just trying to see if I can work my way back to JUST the rotateY

Comment: I misunderstood. thought u want to use the value of transform to do something. disregard the comment. I found a function on this link [Read getRotationDegrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336101/css3-animation-on-transform-rotate-way-to-fetch-current-deg-of-the-rotating-el). And read on the link above to get which value belongs to Y. and use the way they use the function to get Y degree. I'll read on this later tonite if u havent get the answer. sorry for not be helpful enough. on my way to work. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your object is only being rotated about Y, then yes, the rotation is simple to calculate - it's the [arccos of Matrix elements 1,1](https://www.google.com/search?q=arccos%28-1%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=a9e&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=arccos%28-1%29+in+degrees&oq=arccos%28-1%29+in+degrees&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3...5527.7297.0.7423.12.12.0.0.0.0.413.2485.0j7j3j1j1.12.0.eqn%2Crate_low%3D0-015%2Crate_high%3D0-015%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Ccconf%3D0-6.1.0.0.V15oX2ePmt8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=61fe8c406b329c8c&biw=1680&bih=830) or 3,3 or the arsin of -(element 3,1) or arcsin of element 1,3.  In your specific example, it's about 180 degrees.  If the rotations are about more than just the y axis, then you have to start tracking previous rotations and it can get messier.

Your translation will just be the bottom row of the output matrix, 0,0,0 in this case.

See examples on
http://www.inversereality.org/tutorials/graphics%20programming/3dwmatrices.html

Comment: Well, it is a 7 year old thread. You can use the wayback machine on archive.org to see its cached version. Here is the 2011 version from wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20110127040842/http://www.inversereality.org/tutorials/graphics%20programming/3dwmatrices.html

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve transformation informations with the "new WebKitCSSMatrix" function. For example :

```
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix($('#element').css('-webkit-transform'));
var translateZ = matrix.m43;
```

Each part of the matrix is explain here : http://9elements.com/html5demos/matrix3d/
You can retrieve more complexe properties like rotationX, for 3d matrix with math mess :

```
var rotationX = Math.acos(matrix.a) * (180/Math.PI);
var rotationY = Math.asin(matrix.b) * (180/Math.PI);
```

Answer (score 3):

Given function determines `rotation*`, `transform*` and `scale` for given DOM element **cross-browser**.

If you want something more, or find bugs in mathematics, it's a discussion on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489298/inverse-3d-transforms-from-matrix-given-end-formula-needed)

Tested on browsers listed in http://caniuse.com/transforms3d:

```
var reverseEngineerTransform3d = function (domElement, parameterName) {

        parameterName = parameterName.toLowerCase();

        var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(domElement),
            matrixStyle = computedStyle.transform || computedStyle.WebkitTransform || computedStyle.MozTransform || computedStyle.msTransform || computedStyle.OTransform;

        if (matrixStyle) {
            matrixStyle = matrixStyle.trim();
        }

        if (matrixStyle === 'none') {
            if (parameterName.indexOf('rotate') === 0) {
                return '0deg';
            } else if (parameterName.indexOf('translate') === 0) {
                return '0px';
            } else if (parameterName === 'scale') {
                return 1;
            } else {
                throw "Unsupported 3D parameter " + parameterName;
            }
        }

        else if (!matrixStyle || matrixStyle.substr(0, 9) !== 'matrix3d(') {
            //return something or die ?????
            throw "Something is wrong with 3D transform style. Probably no style applied at all OR unknown CSS3 vendor OR unknown/unsupported 3D matrix representation string OR CSS3 3D transform is not fully supported in this browser";
        }

        var matrix = window.WebKitCSSMatrix && (new WebKitCSSMatrix(matrixStyle)) ||
                window.MozCSSMatrix && (new MozCSSMatrix(matrixStyle)) ||
                window.MsCSSMatrix && (new MsCSSMatrix(matrixStyle)) ||
                window.OCSSMatrix && (new OCSSMatrix(matrixStyle)) ||
                window.CSSMatrix && (new CSSMatrix(matrixStyle)); // sorry 4 copy-paste my friends

        if (!matrix || isNaN(matrix.a) || isNaN(matrix.b) || isNaN(matrix.c) || isNaN(matrix.m41) || isNaN(matrix.m42) || isNaN(matrix.m43) || isNaN(matrix.m11)) {
            throw "Could not catch CSSMatrix constructor for current browser, OR the constructor has returned a non-standard matrix object (need .a, .b, .c and mXX numerical properties to work)";
        }


        // todo: giving a parameters array (and returning an array) is a good idea, or we could return everything if no parameters given

        switch (parameterName) {

            case 'rotatey':  // in degrees
                return Math.acos(matrix.m11)*180/Math.PI * (matrix.m13 > 0 ? -1 : 1) + 'deg';

            case 'rotatex':  // in degrees
                return Math.asin(matrix.m22)*180/Math.PI + 'deg';

            case 'rotatez':  // in degrees
                throw "TODO: Sorry, math people. I really need help here! Please implement this case for me. This will help you: http://9elements.com/html5demos/matrix3d/";

            case 'translatex': // in pixels
                return matrix.m41 + 'px';

            case 'translatey': // in pixels
                return matrix.m42 + 'px';

            case 'translatez': // in pixels
                return matrix.m43 + 'px';

            case 'scale': // no units
                if (matrix.m11 === matrix.m22 && matrix.m22 === matrix.m33) {
                    return matrix.m11;
                } else {
                    throw "I'm not so smart to calculate scale from this matrix";
                }

           // todo: anything else? skew ????

            default:
                throw "This function accepts 3d-parameter name (case-insensitive string) as the second argument. Currently supported: 'rotate[xyz]', 'translate[xyz]', 'scale'. This parameter is unsupported: " + parameterName;
        }
    };
```

Comment: One with better math skills can extend the function possibilities. Once we have the matrix, we can reverse-engineer a lot of things

Comment: // Todo: a good article I will process soon: http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/