# Catch CSS value before mouse leaves

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I'd like to get the current value of my `transform: rotate`, just before the mouse leaves. In the current state, the event seems to be caught when the mouse has already left my button and returns `0deg` which is true at this moment.

My point is to play the same animation in reverse mode. For that, I need to get the current value of the rotation and make a transition from `Xdeg` to `0deg`. I firstly tried to accomplish it in full CSS but the animation is suddenly broken when mouse leaves. I also tried to play another animation when the mouse is not on the button but the result is not as clean as I expected since it begins from a predefined value and not the current rotate value.

You can find my fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/yn460w6j/

Thanks to [@lakenen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336101/css3-animation-on-transform-rotate-way-to-fetch-current-deg-of-the-rotating-el) for the degree function, btw !

Comment: It seems to get the proper angle on Firefox

Comment: Indeed ! Why does it fail in Chrome then ? Works in Edge too.

Comment: Note CSS transforms is only a draft. It's not much stable, and implementations are not fully interoperable.

Comment: The problem seems to be more the `mouseleave` event himself than the CSS transform. No ? And it's quite surprising that Chrome is not on the page for this property while Firefox and Edge are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I little play with that, use only js to solve this. I'm adding class to spinner when mouseover on button. Next, when mouseleave I am setting listener on stop animation iteration. When it complete I just remove animation class from spinner.

```
var $spinner = $("#random_glyph");
var $button = $("#random_button");            

$button.on("mouseover", function() { 
    $spinner.addClass('animation');
 });

$button.on("mouseleave", function() {
    $button.bind("webkitAnimationIteration, mozAnimationIteration, animationiteration", function(e){    
        $spinner.removeClass('animation');  
        $(this).unbind(e);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jLstovx/

Comment: Aw ! Even a simplier solution than what I was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: @Quinox Glad to help :)