# How can I know if a div is rotating?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I have a div, I can rotate it to some degree by using

> rotateX(degree)

In css3 I set

> transition: 2s

The div will begin rotating and stop in 2s. Here is my problem:
How can I get if the div is rotating or stopped?

Thanks.

Comment: There are events for when a animation starts or stops

Comment: if you're using transition, you could use `transitionend` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps, you can leverage the 'transitioned' event, to check when the element's transition has stopped, like so:

```js
let hasRotated = false
div.addEventListener('transitionend', () => hasRotated = true);
```

More on the event here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event

Answer (score 2):

Aÿlo already gave a good answer. But, `animationstart` method may have a problem of compatibility.
[animationstart](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_animationstart_event) useage value: 96.77%

If compatibility is important, I think it would be good to add the `getComputedStyle` method as a fallback.
[getComputedStyle](https://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle) useage value: 99.72%

Using the `getComputedStyle` fallback method, you can write the code as below.

```js
const DEGREE_BY_ONE_SEC = 90
const DEGREE_SEC = 2
let hasRotated = false

div.addEventListener('transitionend', () => hasRotated = true); // Aÿlo's code
window.setTimeout(() => {
  const rotationDegrees = getRotationDegrees(element) // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351437/11618421
  if (rotationDegrees === DEGREE_BY_ONE_SEC * DEGREE_SEC) {
    hasRotated = true
    return
  }
}, DEGREE_SEC)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransitionEvent#types_of_transitionevent) related to the `transition`s that you may use.

Here's a simple live demo to get you started:

```js
const rotatingDiv = document.getElementById('rotating');

/** listen for transition start */
rotatingDiv.addEventListener('transitionstart', () => console.log('transition started..'));

/** transition is running */
rotatingDiv.addEventListener('transitionrun', () => console.log('transition running....'));

/** listen for transition end */
rotatingDiv.addEventListener('transitionend', () => console.log('transition finished.'));
```

```css
/** for demo purposes only */
#rotating {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  transition: transform 2s 0s ease;
}

#rotating:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg); /** change this per your requirement */
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 80px!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotating">
  <div>
```

> The above demo showcases the events related to `CSS transition`s. If you'd need to use animation instead, then you should look into animation related events like the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event) event.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript's setTimeout function, which waits some milliseconds before calling a function.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Div has stopped rotating.");
}, 2000)
```